# Git flow (release/hotfix) on support branches (LTS)

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using git-flow for my codebase, and we are really happy. Yet, there's a conceptual problem with the support branch.

I've a support branch for the version `1.x` . Sometimes I've to apply hotfix, or create a new release (feature is very unlikely).

- Is there a way to create a release from a support branch that is merged only in the support branch? (basically i would like to have the same `git flow` commands but based on the `support` branch rather than the `master` one.)
- Is there a way to create an hotfix and have it applied to the support branch (i guess here is a matter of cerrypicking, since the code diverges a lot usually)
- Is this the correct way to mantain a LTS version?

Comment: For a `hotfix` you can just branch off of `support` and merge it back in to `support`. As for a new `release` based off of an older one, I don't think there's a well defined answer in Git Flow. I'd probably just call that a conceptually "big" hotfix and also go off of `support`. As for the Git Flow commands, it may be easier to just do the commands you need manually in this case.